# How can I prove I do not own real-estate property in New Jersey?

Tags: real-estate, new-jersey

For purposes of tax exemption in another country, I need to prove that I do not own a house or an apartment in my current state of residence, which is New Jersey. How can I do that?

For example, is there a way to search my identity (SSN) in property records and get an official document verifying there are no matching results?

Comment: It's quite difficult to prove a negative.  Since property records, in the US anyway, is nearly always at the county level, you would somehow have to get some documentation from every county in NJ stating that you did not own property there.  I doubt it's index by SSN.  You might contact a local title search company, for a (likely large) fee they could probably provide you with a records search that doesn't show any current ownership.

Comment: Do you need to prove that you do not own ANYTHING in the state, or just that you do not own where you currently reside?

Comment: @EugeneStyer I need to prove that I do not own any real estate.

Comment: Would a rental lease suffice?

Answer (score 5):

> For example, is there a way to search my identity (SSN) in property
> records and get an official document verifying there are no matching
> results?

No. You can search by name on a county by county basis, however.

A certified search result from your county of residence to corroborate you affidavit or declaration and attached as an exhibit to the affidavit or declaration might be worth including (even if it is something of a matter of form over substance). You might also considering attaching a copy of your lease to the place where you reside in New Jersey if you have one. Both of these documents would only corroborate that you don't own what you claim to be your residential address, rather than proving by themselves that you own no real estate in New Jersey. But the authorities you are seeking to prove something to will inevitably have to take you at your word regarding what your residential address is anyway.

> For purposes of tax exemption in another country, I need to prove that
> I do not own a house or an apartment in my current state of residence,
> which is New Jersey. How can I do that?

Usually, you would do this by executing an affidavit or declaration under the penalty of perjury to that effect.

Comment: Thank you. I was also assuming an affidavit is the way to go, but I was told (and am still trying to find an official source for that), that it won't be enough, and I need some kind of an official document. Based on the idea in your answer, I'm now considering submitting the (empty) search results of all 21 NJ counties, either directly, or through a title search company as @jwh20 suggested in a comment.

Comment: @OfriRaviv Best of luck.